# No current_user for Rails API using DeviseTokenAuth and Ionic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ionic-framework

I'm trying to access the Devise `:authenticate_user!` method in my API. I've followed the [Devise Token Auth gem](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#concerns), but I cannot access the `current_user` variable/helper method within my API controller when accessing through Ionic with json.

User.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
include DeviseInvitable::Inviter
devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable,
     :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :timeoutable,
     :invitable, :invite_for => 2.weeks
include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
```

Application.rb

```
class Application < Rails::Application
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins "*"
    resource "*",
      headers: :any,
      expose: ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
      methods: [:get, :put, :post, :delete, :options]
  end
end
```

Api Controller:

```
module Api
  class MobileController < ApplicationController
    include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
    respond_to :json
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def facility_contacts
      @facility = current_user.facility
    end
  end
end
```

Devise User::SessionsController

```
class User::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken

  respond_to :json, :html

  def create
    sign_out(:user) if current_user
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
end
```

Ionic app service and controller:

```
.factory('UserSession', function($resource) {
  return $resource("http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json")
})

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $location, UserSession, $ionicPopup, $rootScope) {
  $scope.data = {}
  $scope.login = function() {
  var user_session = new UserSession({ user: $scope.data })
  user_session.$save(
    function(data) {
      window.localStorage['userId'] = data.id
      window.localStorage['userName'] = data.name
      $location.path('/tab/daily_updates')
    },
    function(err) {
      var error = err['data']['error'] || err.data.join('.')
      var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'An error occured',
        template: error
      })
    }
  )
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

Remove `protect_from_forgery` in ApplicationController.

I had set it to null_session, which was somehow removing the cookie and/or the current_user from within the Devise setup.

Comment: ... But if you remove `protect_from_forgery`, are you still protected from forgery?...

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on this demo app, but I think the big issue with the Rails' `protect_from_forgery` method in this case was the `verify_same_origin_request` method that gets called. We were having a lot of cross origin request failures.
Looking at the source code now, we were able to keep the `protect_from_forgery` method. Don't remember how we fixed this issue!
Thinking about it now, I'd go with a Rails + React Native setup.  :)